# When ever I press a media key on my keyboard, Windows Mail opens

Tags: keyboard, windows-8.1, wireless-keyboard, function-keys

This just started last night out of no where - I was listening to music and playing League of Legends.

A song came on that I didn't wish to listen to, so I went to press the *Next Song* Media Key that comes on my keyboard, and my game minimized and opened up Windows Mail, but this happens with every function key on my keyboard, such as *opening my browser in its home page*, *opening my media player*, *skip/play/pause songs*, *mute*, or *turning up or down the volume*.

Any of these keys trigger Windows Mail to open up.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I looked it up and tried:

- a fix about reinstalling the drivers for my wireless mouse/keyboard: **No fix**.
- rebooting my PC to see if that was the issues. **No fix**.

By the way I am using a MK320 Wireless Keyboard/Mouse that I bought two years ago. Also I am running Windows 8.1.

Comment: Try using the *on-screen keyboard*, to check whether a program in Windows is changing the behaviour of the input from the physical keyboard, or whether the physical keyboard is the problem

Comment: The onscreen keyboard doesn't have the media keys so there is no way i can test it.

Comment: can you not press the on screen FN key and the top numbers change to the media keys? That works for me

Answer (score 7):

I just had a problem with my Logitec keyboard where the email would initiate every time I touched a volume button.
I turned the keyboard off for 10 seconds then turned it back on and it fixed it.

Comment: Thx! That solved it for me. Strange that logitech did not fixed the bug yet after so many years.

Comment: Amazing! I had looked at so many things before I found this! Weird stuff.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same issue with a slightly newer version of the keyboard....After a few hours of reinstalling drivers, starting and stopping windows services, and contacting windows tech support, I eventually figured out how to fix the issue

As far as I can tell, the keyboard's firmware is slightly bugged, and the problem can be fixed by removing the battery for a few seconds.